# Take the Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Take the Laplace transform of

> $$ \int_{0}^{t}x^2(x-t)^4 \cos(x)dx .$$

I'm not quite sure where to start...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the convolution property for the Laplace transform

> $$\mathcal{L}(f*g) =\mathcal{L}(f)\mathcal{L}(g). $$

See this [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755760/laplace-transform-of-integral-equation/755804#755804).

**Note:** You can take $f(x)=x^4 $ and $g(x)=x^2\cos(x)$. Finding the Laplace transform of $x^4$ is easy. For $g(x)=x^2\cos(x)$ you can use the Laplace property

> $$ \mathcal{L}(x^nh(x)) = (-1)^n H^{(n)}(s), $$

where $H(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $h(x)$.

Comment: Okay. So the Laplace of x^4 would be 4!/s^5. Cool. So that would mean that I have to take the second derivative of x^2cos(x)? To do this I would change it to be -1(d/ds)L(h(x)) where h(x) is cos(x)?

Comment: @Jay: To find Laplace transform of $x^2\cos(x)$, you need to differentiate twice the the Laplace transform of $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

I had not found any other way than to follow the above suggested. So I just did the labor calculation.

From $$\mathcal{L}(f*g) =\mathcal{L}(f)\mathcal{L}(g),$$ we can set

$f(x)=x^2\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=x^4$ and

Since $\mathcal{L}[(-t)^nf(t)]=F^{(n)}(s)$, we can find that
$$\mathcal{L}[t^2\cos(t)]=\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\frac{s}{s^2 + 1}=\frac{2s(s^2-3)}{(s^2 + 1)^3}$$
and together with $\mathcal{L}[t^4]=\frac{4!}{s^5}$, the final answer will be
$$
\mathcal{L}[x^2\cos(x)*x^4]=\frac{2s(s^2-3)}{(s^2 + 1)^3}\frac{4!}{s^5}=\frac{48(s^2-3)}{s^4(s^2 + 1)^3}.
$$